# Liferay does not save settings after change the DB from Hypersonic to MySQL

Tags: database, liferay

when I have changed the Liferay database from Hypersonic to MySQL seems that the settings of the pages and all the customization done in Liferay through the web GUI are not saved. What can be the problem?

This is my configuration of the portal-ext.properties:

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
jdbc.default.username=root
jdbc.default.password=liferay
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have-you restart Liferay after portal-ext.properties update ?

Answer (score 5):

Liferay will not migrate databases for you automatically. To do it manually,

1. Startup Liferay using your HSQLDB database (the source database) and have your destination database ready.
2. Login as the administrator.
3. Goto the Control Panel > Server Administration > Data Migration.
4. Fill out the information under "Please enter JDBC information for new database."

   - This info will be the same to the data you've entered for your portal-ext.properties
5. Hit Execute.

Your data should begin migrating.

I would also highly advise that you do not allow users to access the database while running the data migration tool.

After the migration has completed, shut down Liferay and reconfigure your portal using the new database and start up again!